# Microsoft Graph API unable to see Planner tasks on mobile application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am creating Microsoft Planner tasks using Microsoft graph API. Tasks get created and are visible on Planner web application, but same tasks are not vissible on mobile application (although I am signing in with the same username).

Only tasks that are seen in Planner are the ones that are manually created in Microsoft planner.

Application is creating tasks for other employees, but not sure how can I see tasks on web Microsoft Planner but not on mobile version.

Comment: Mobile will show the same tasks as web. To identify the mismatch here we need more information:
Are you assigning the tasks?
What kind of Plan are the tasks created in (e.g. what is the container type of the plan)?
Who has access to the plan?
Which mobile app are you using?

Comment: @TarkanSevilmis Our Application is assigning the tasks through Microsoft Graph API. Not sure what kind of Plan it is, all employees have access to the Plan. A bit more info, tasks are actually visible to some employees on mobile app (we tryed on Android and IOS), but APP crashes when we try to open tasks created throught API.